# Access the header template value of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

How can I access the header template value of a DataGrid from the code behind?

I have an image button in the header template and I want to access that image button from code behind.

```html
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSelectAll" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/check.gif" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcb" Checked="False" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx). You can just the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event

```
gv.RowDataBound+=(s,ev)=>
    {
        if(ev.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            ((Image)ev.Row.FindControl("imgSelectAll")).ImageUrl="SomePath";
        }
    };
```

Or if you are using the [datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) you can use [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx)

```
gv.ItemDataBound+=(s,ev)=>
    {
        if(ev.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Header)
        {
            ((Image)ev.Item.FindControl("imgSelectAll")).ImageUrl="SomePath";
        }
    };
```

Comment: I know that is why I have a part of datagrid as well